# Typescript: Create class via constructor passing in named parameters?

Tags: typescript, named-parameters

I have a class where I have the constructor defined with 3 parameters which are all optional. I was hoping to be able to pass in named parameters so I don't need to pass in undefined.

```
constructor(year?: number,
            month?: number,
            date?: number)
```

I was hoping to create an intance of the class like so

```
  const recurrenceRule = new MyNewClass(month: 6)
```

but it didn't work and i tried

```
  const recurrenceRule = new MyNewClass(month = 6)
```

and that didn't work.

The only way i got it to work was either

```
  const recurrenceRule = new MyNewClass(undefined, 4)
```

or

```
  const recurrenceRule = new MyNewClass(, 4)
```

But it seems so messy, I was hoping to pass in named arguments and becasue they are all optional I should be able to just pass in 1 - right ?

Comment: The only languages that have this feature and I'm aware of are Swift and Python

Comment: you can pass in an interface object, but like @Vivick said, this feature doesn't exist in TS

Comment: @Vivick C# has had it for a long time too.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use Object destructuring introduced in ES6 to achieve the desired behavior: [reference](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_object-destructuring). TypeScript is able to transpile this feature for usage with ES5 to target older browsers. However, as of ES6, this is also perfectly valid JavaScript.

Basically, it looks like this: `constructor({ year, month, day})` and is invoked, for instance, as `new Bar({ year: 2017 })`. Then you can access `year` as a variable within the constructor, e.g. for assigning `this.year = year`.

More interesting than that is the usage with **default values**, e.g.

```
constructor({ year = new Date().getFullYear(), 
              month = new Date().getMonth(), 
              day = new Date().getDay()
            } = {})
```

which allows invoking the constructor with 0, 1, 2 or 3 parameters respectively (see snippet below).

The somewhat cryptic `= {}` is for the case when you create a new instance without any parameters. First, `{}` is used as the default value for the parameter object. Then, since `year` is missing, the default value for that one is added, then for month and for day respectively.

For usage with TypeScript, you can, of course, add additional typings,

```
constructor({ year = new Date().getFullYear(),
              month = new Date().getMonth(),
              day = new Date().getDay()
}: { year?: number, month?: number, day?: number } = {}) { 
    ...                
}
```

Although this *really* looks cryptic.

```js
class Bar {
  constructor({ year, month, day }) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
  }
  
  log () {
    console.log(`year: ${this.year}, month: ${this.month}, day: ${this.day}`);
  }
}

new Bar({ day: 2017 }).log();

class Foo {
  constructor({ year = new Date().getFullYear(), 
                month = new Date().getMonth(), 
                day = new Date().getDay()
              } = {}) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
  }
  
  log () {
    console.log(`year: ${this.year}, month: ${this.month}, day: ${this.day}`);
  }
}

console.log('with default value:');
new Foo().log();
new Foo({ day: 2 }).log();
new Foo({ day: 2, month: 8 }).log();
new Foo({ year: 2015 }).log();
```

Comment: Are you using some special compilerOptions? I'm getting `Property 'year' does not exist on type 'Bar'`. ("target": "es2021", "esModuleInterop": true)

Answer (score 23):

```
class Bar {
  constructor({a, b}: {a?: number, b?: number}) {}
}

new Bar({b: 1})
```

For more information, see [ES6 Object Destructuring with functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#ES2015_version).

Comment: I like this solution

Comment: Doesn't work. A `console.log()` on `new Bar({b: 1})` gives `Bar {}`

Comment: @TBG You still have to assign the parameters in the constructor like `this.b = b` if you want them to appear as properties on the class. A shorthand for this would be nice since it's what you often want, but Typescript is not designed for concision.

Answer (score 6):

Simple parameter:

```
constructor (private recurrenceSettings: {year?: number, month?: number, date?: number})
```

The private keyword instantiates argument as an instance variable, saving you needing to instantiate in the constructor.  Can also be `public` if you want to instatiate public properties.

Use like this:

```
const recurrenceRule = new MyClass({month: 12})
```

Or use destructuring (usage same as above):

```
constructor({day, month, year}: {day?: number, month?: number, year?: number})
```

The above version loses the ability to use the private/public shortcut for instance variables though (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326).

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to achieve the same result.

You would instantiate the same way as in the previous answers.

```js
class Bar {
  year = new Date().getFullYear();
  month = new Date().getMonth();
  day = new Date().getDay();
  constructor(bar?: Partial<Bar>) {
    Object.assign(this, bar);
  }
  
  log () {
    console.log(`year: ${this.year}, month: ${this.month}, day: ${this.day}`);
  }
}

new Bar().log();
new Bar({ day: 2 }).log();
new Bar({ day: 2, month: 8 }).log();
new Bar({ year: 2015 }).log();
```

Note 1. The `Partial<Bar>` will accept anything as long as the properties of the same name have the same type. Yes, this somewhat violates type-safety. The reason this is still powerful is that if you start typing an object literal with `{`, the intellisense will tell you what properties you can initialize.

Note 2. The `Object.assign` will disregard `readonly` properties since it is a JavaScript-specific thing, not TypeScript-specific. This means that while you can't assign a `readonly` property a new value, you certainly can with `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems this still isn't as easily possible as it could be, though it would be nice.

But the solution only took a few minutes.

Here's what I did.. I used [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55483981/3917091) to get a list of properties minus methods.

```
export class Member {
    private constructor(public memberID: number = -1,
        public email: string = '',
        public loggedIn: boolean = false) {
    }

    static newByNamed(obj: NonFunctionProperties<Member>) {
        Object.assign(new Member(), obj);
    }
    
    public clear() {
        this.memberID = config.nonExistentID;
        this.email = '';
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}

type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
  }[keyof T];

type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
```

And then I can call it with

```
let member = Member.newByNamed({email = 'me@home'...});
```

Comment: Do the default values in the constructor really work? I cannot compile until I have all the optional parameters passed in. So in your case I need to write `let member = Member.newByNamed({ memberID: 3, email: 'sdf', loggedIn: true })`

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it's just easier to have an interface and separate maker function. (For future readers.)

```
interface Foo {
  x: number
  y: number
}

function newFoo({x=5,y=10}) : Foo {return {x,y}}

const f = newFoo({x:100})
```