# Typescript: Mapped Types: Class to Interface without methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-2.5

Is it possible to write a Mapped Type that transforms a Class into an Interface minus the class's methods or any properties assigned to the `prototype`. EG,

```
class Dog {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    bark() {}
    get dogYears(): number {
        return this.age * 7;
    }
}

type InterfaceOf<T> = { /* ??? */ };
type IDog = InterfaceOf<Dog>;
// equivalent to
interface IDog {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

---

**Why do I want to do this?**
I'm looking to "deserialize" json objects into classes. Eg, I run a query to get dogs from the database, afterwards I'd like to instantiate them into class objects, perhaps by using the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library.

```
function queryDogs(): Promise<{ name: string, age: string }[]>;
function deserialize<T>(cls: (new() => T), input: InterfaceOf<T>): T;
function deserialize<T>(cls: (new() => T), inputs: InterfaceOf<T>[]): T[];

class Dog {
    @Type(() => String)
    name: string;
    @Type(() => Number)
    age: number;
    bark() {}
    get dogYears(): number {
        return this.age * 7;
    }
}

const dbDogs = await queryDogs();
const dogs: Dog[] = deserialize(Dog, dogs);
```

It would be nice if the `deserialize` function knew if the input was the right shape to be deserialized into the Dog class. I was hoping it could look at the `Dog` class that is given to it to transform it into the appropriate interface.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Interface Based on Class

You can directly generate an interface from a class in TypeScript:

```
interface DogLike extends Dog {

}
```

The Angular community is all over this, but beware of [some warnings about using classes as interfaces](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/11/typescript-using-classes-interfaces/).

The interface that this would generate for you would include properties and methods:

```
interface DogLike {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    bark(): void;
    dogYears: number;
}
```

## Mapped Type Madness

Now, you can [do something really clever/complex/mad with mapped types, based on the mapped types found in this article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/11/typescript-mighty-morphing-mapped-types/).

```
type Remove<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type RemoveProperty<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in Remove<keyof T, K>]: T[P] };

type PartDog = RemoveProperty<DogLike, 'bark' | 'dogYears'>;
```

This takes the `DogLike` interface, and removes `bark` and `dogYears`.

I included this as you mentioned mapped types. However, it is an insane solution.

## Interface

My recommended solution, would be a a simple interface, and perhaps one that isn't named after dogs at all, as the properties are more general:

```
interface NamedLivingOrganism {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Okay, you may not name it exactly like that. However, simple is often best and when you come to change either the `Dog` class, or the interface that is loosely based on it at some point in the future, the simple interface will prove to be the best way to represent what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the warning. I updated my question with  an example of how I could use it. I feel like my use-case doesn't quite fall into that warning scenario. Perhaps using Typescript decorators in this way should come with similar warnings?

Comment: I'd also like to suggest that there is also the `Pick<T, 'name' | 'age'>` approach which is almost as painful as the the `Remove` approach.

Another problem with the `Pick` and `Remove` approaches is they break down for nested classes, eg if the `Dog` class had an `owner` property of `Human`

Comment: After seeing the madness of Mapped Type Madness, I realised the Interface solution was the simplest for my case, so thank you for showing me the bottom of the rabbit hole =D

Answer (score 17):

It's possible to define the IDog type without methods, as [described in TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). But unfortunately it still contains dogYears getter. As I know, it cannot be solved because when dealing with types, there is no difference between fields and getters.

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

type IDog = NonFunctionProperties<Dog>;
```

Comment: The secret is in `{...}[keyof T]` syntax, described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). It compiles the type as a union of the properties except if its types wasn't `"never"`. So, for type `type AAnyType = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", fn1: never };` (mapped by `{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }`), the type `type NoNeverUnion = AAnyType["foo" | "bar" | "fn1"];` maps `"foo" | "bar"`, and `"foo" | "bar" | "fn1"` is maped by `keyof AAnyType`, so `AAnyType[keyof AAnyType];` has the same effect. Very well. Thank you.

Comment: This is so elegant, thank you. I used it to make a sort of factory with named arguments, without having to type everything twice. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72478300/3917091

Comment: Is there a ready lib that provides this type?